# javascript script source won't be found by browser zendframework

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

I'm trying to import a script into my .phtml file.

```
<body>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></SCRIPT>

</body>
```

But the browser console returns me an error message:
error with loading  source `"http://myhost/a/script.js"`

My project structure is:

app/module/someName/view/a/b/script.js

app/module/someName/view/a/b/index.phtml

I can include my php files laying in the same directory into my index.phtml. But somehow when i want to include the java script code I get an error.

My guess was i use the InvokableFactory with my controller. Is there some correlation?

module.config.php

```
'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'a' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/a',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => MonitoringController::class,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'child_routes' => [


            'b' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/b[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => DashboardController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

Comment: If your phtml is located under `/a/b/` then why does the error message say `http://myhost/a/`?

Comment: I think because of my routing configuration I guess. I updated my post with the modules.config.php

Comment: Is "myhost" a virtual host? If so, what is the document root set to? (Typically this would point at the `public` folder in your Zend Framework app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the script with php and now it works good.

```
$this->inlineScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('pathTo/javaScriptFile.js'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `src="script.js"` with `src="/b/script.js"`

Comment: Phpstorm is fine with src="script.js", i get an error if i change to src="/b/script.js"

Comment: Have you checked the browser console ?

based on the error you wrote above, my suggestion must solve you problem. PHP storm try to load the .js file using absolute path to the file. 

You browser is trying to laod from current URL. 

`http://myhost/a/script.js` means that you position, based on URL is `http://myhost/a` adding `/b/scripts.js` make the browser to serch on subdirectory b for the script.

Comment: It just returns me that the script could not be loaded without any error number.

Comment: I use version 3.

Comment: You can move your .js to `./public/js/{module}/scripts.js` to make it public, then include it using `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/{module}/scripts.js"></script>` replace {module} with you module name. Otherwise you can check Zend official doc on how to include script files in a view file. https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-view/helpers/head-script/

Comment: Browser still won't find it and returns source not found "http://myhost/public/js/anzahlBuchungen.js".

Comment: Have you 'physically moved' the .js file to ./public/js directory?

Comment: When you go on the site home page what  is the URL? Try to open `http://myhost/public/js/` or  `http://myhost/js/` in you browser, if the first one failes that means your application is already running under /public.